# Query using three tables, joining 2, counting records where 2 columns match from 3rd?

Tags: sql

I need to find which course offerings are currently full (the number of students enrolled equals the
capacity of the room it is held in)? For each of the course offerings in the results, list its
symbol, number, section number, building, room number, and capacity.

I know the three tables I need to use are these enrolled, courseoffering_of, and location with these inserts:

```
INSERT INTO enrolled (netID, symbol, number, sectionNumber) VALUES
('aec3', 'CSE', '4503', '01'),
('hc23', 'CSE', '1384', '02'),
('jjc13', 'CSE', '1384', '02'),
('wp4', 'CSE', '1384', '02' );

INSERT INTO courseoffering_of (symbol, `number`, building, room, 
sectionNumber) VALUES
('CSE', '4503', 'Butler', '100', '01'),
('CSE', '1384', 'Butler', '103', '01'),
('CSE', '1384', 'Butler', '103', '02'),
('ECE', '4713', 'Old Main', '2830', '01');

INSERT INTO location (building, room, capacity) VALUES
('Butler', '100', 5),
('Butler', '102', 2),
('Butler', '103', 2),
('Old Main', '2830', 6),
('Old Main', '3030', 3);`
```

I came up with some pseudocode to help me solve it:

```
1. merge courseoffering_of and location tables
2. count students in each class from enrolled (same number and section number)
3. select where class from enrolled = class from merged table (same number 
and section number)
4. compare number of students counted in that class with room capacity
5. if students enrolled = room capacity return the entry from merged table
```

I have no idea what to do for this query. I originally thought creating a new table from courseoffering_of and location would help, but our teacher wants us to do this all in a single query. I tried an inner join but couldn't figure out how to use it in this situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you try CTE?

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start here:

```
select symbol,number,sectionNumber, count(*) as count_enrolled
from enrolled
group by symbol,number,sectionNumber
```

Above query will return how many students were enrolled for each course:

```
symbol  number  sectionNumber   count_enrolled
CSE     1384    02              3
CSE     4503    01              1
```

Then we need to find the room capacity:

```
select c.*,l.capacity
from courseoffering_of c
join location l
on c.building = l.building
and c.room = l.room
```

The output is:

```
symbol  number  building    room    sectionNumber   capacity
CSE     4503    Butler      100     01              5
CSE     1384    Butler      103     01              2
CSE     1384    Butler      103     02              2
ECE     4713    Old Main    2830    01              6
```

Now it is time to combine those of queries:

```
select c.*,l.capacity
,a.count_enrolled
from courseoffering_of c
join location l
on c.building = l.building
and c.room = l.room
join 
(select symbol,number,sectionNumber, count(*) as count_enrolled
from enrolled
group by symbol,number,sectionNumber) a
on c.symbol = a.symbol
and c.number = a.number
and c.sectionNumber = a.sectionNumber
```

You will get:

```
symbol      number  building    room    sectionNumber   capacity count_enrolled
CSE         4503    Butler      100     01              5           1
CSE         1384    Butler      103     02              2           3
```

Finally, pick the full courses.

```
select * from (
select c.*,l.capacity
,a.count_enrolled
from courseoffering_of c
join location l
on c.building = l.building
and c.room = l.room
join 
(select symbol,number,sectionNumber, count(*) as count_enrolled
from enrolled
group by symbol,number,sectionNumber) a
on c.symbol = a.symbol
and c.number = a.number
and c.sectionNumber = a.sectionNumber)b
where b.capacity <= b.count_enrolled
```

Here is the test result:
[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f004d9672dbcbbb316092ec2bc4f08ca)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, and the explanation as well. I have been misunderstanding group by so this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.symbol, c.number, c.sectionNumber FROM
courseoffering_of c
INNER JOIN
location l
ON
l.building = c.building
AND
l.room = c.room
INNER JOIN
enrolled e
ON
e.number = c.number
AND
e.sectionNumber = c.sectionNumber
GROUP BY c.symbol, c.number, c.sectionNumber, l.capacity 
HAVING count(*) >= l.capacity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try the following query

    with CTE_temp1 as
     (
      select symbol, number, count(number) Total_student, sectionNumber from enrolled
      group by symbol, number, sectionnumber
     )

    ,CTE_temp2 as
     (
      select a.symbol, a.number, a.building, a.room, a.sectionNumber, b.capacity
      from course_offering_of a inner join location b
      on a.location = b.location
      and a.room = b.room 
     )


     select a.symbol, a.number, a.building, a.room, a.sectionNumber 
     from CTE_temp2 a inner join CTE_temp1 b 
     on a.symbol = b.symbol
     and a.number = b.number
     and a.sectionNumber = b.sectionNumber
     where a.capacity = b.Total_student
```